# Creating a highscore system using Vectors

Tags: c++, directx

Im currently learning c++ and directx 9. I am creating a small game which I want to have a high score system, I have the reading and writing of the files done, I am just stuck on how to sort and insert a new value into my score vector.

My method for reading files into a vector is below:

```
     vector<int> Highscore::readFile()
     {
      int score;
       highScoreIn.open ("Highscore.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
       if (highScoreIn.is_open())
       {

       while(highScoreIn>>score)
         {
           scores.push_back(score);
         }
         highScoreIn.close();
    return(scores);
       }
       else cout << "Unable to open file"; 
     }
```

I want a function that will check an integer passed into the function against the 5 values I am storing in the vector scores, then insert it into the right place in the vector. Any help on this would be appreciated:)

Comment: what do you mean by insert it into the right place? are the scores inside your vector already sorted?

Comment: I am sorting my vector using this line:

sort(scores.rbegin(), scores.rend());

Comment: just put the integer into the vector and sort it again should work. You would like the vector to be sorted whenever you insert a new score into it? You may consider using set instead if your scores do not have duplicates

Comment: Ideally I want a structure of some sort to hold 5 scores, then check one new score to see if it is a new high score, if it is I want it to return a bool and insert the new score into the structure, im not sure if vectors are the best tool for this task, but its all I know how to use at the moment:/

Comment: if you always keep size 5, you may consider use heap instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your vector is sorted from largest to smallest

```
bool insert( vector<int> &v, int n ) {
    for ( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(), ++it ) {
        if ( *it < n ) {
            v.insert( it, n );
            v.pop_back()
            return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
}
```